# Same URL shows two different images when being opened by Google Chrome / Safari?

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, url, safari, png

Can someone explain to me why this same URL shows two different images when being opened by Chrome / Safari?

My friend sent me an image of a girl on Facebook messenger which whenever clicked on, shows an inappropriate image instead of the original girl's picture. I inspected the image on the Console and found the following link.

Which lead to a stranger finding, this same link when opened by Chrome will shows an inappropriate picture, and when opened by Safari will shows the picture of a girl.

Here's the link, as far as I know, "scontent" is one of the servers that store images and videos of Facebook:

> https://scontent.fsgn8-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/34817678_10216866524084121_6779742482465816576_n.png?_nc_cat=0&oh=bfc10e8d9f59f4401e3800208aca56e6&oe=5B7D5AC6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is is trickery with the alpha channel. The headlight image is encoded in the alpha channel. With a black background, the girl disappears and the headlights appear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just accidentally found out about the trick of this image yesterday as well. Was dragging the image across a white background and all of a sudden, the girl appears again. So the trick is the image itself, took me quite some hours inspecting the code. I thought that someone managed to manipulate Facebook code and able to send something that redirect you to a different URL every time you click on it!